# Loading JSON Data with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to follow this tutorial: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/10/json-jquery-ajax-php.html

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/9ujd8s8r/1/

How comes that it doesn't load the JSON data into the page with this code?

```
$(function () {
    $(".load").click(function () {
        $.getJSON("http://demos.9lessons.info/data.json", function (data) {
            $.each(data.posts, function (i, data) {
                var div_data = "<div class='box'><a href='" + data.url + "'>" + data.title + "</a></div>";

                $(div_data).appendTo("#9lessonsLinks");
            });
        });
        return false;
    });


});
```

Comment: You have not define "9lessonsLinks" id anywhere in the html. define it. due to that your data is not populating.

Comment: By the way, [mentioned site](http://www.9lessons.info/2009/10/json-jquery-ajax-php.html) has awful code indentation. To be honest, it doesn't have code indentation at all...

Answer (score 1):

Check your console for errors.  The following error is showing:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://demos.9lessons.info/data.json. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

For more information see ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource).

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. It's a problem of crossdomain. You try to access resource in another server which has not defined that you can.

> http://jquery-howto.blogspot.fr/2013/09/jquery-cross-domain-ajax-request.html

Comment: Note: JSONP won't help here as the server doesn't provide a JSONP service.

Comment: Yes but there is 5 other methods which can maybe help

Comment: Yes, and I was simply pointing out that one of them won't work.